# How do I view my uploaded pdf file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5.5

Hey guys need your help on this one. I find the file system of laravel 5.5  confusing I read the docs but I'm still confused, how do I retrieve and view the file that I uploaded? Here's my controller:

*SoleDistcontroller.blade.php*

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $Record=new SoleDist;
        $Record->name = $request->get('name');
        $Record->address = $request->get('address');
        $path = Storage::putFile('certificates',$request->file('certificate'));
        $Record->file_name = $path;
        $Record->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message','Sole Distributor added successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        $Record = SoleDist::find($id);
        $url = Storage::get($Record->file_name);
        return redirect($url);
    }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: I don't get it I've been over that over and over again and I cant view my PDF File

Comment: But your code looks nothing like [the sample code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#storing-uploaded-files) given there. It's as simple as `$request->certificate->storeAs("directory_name", "filename", "public");` Then it's in your public storage so you just use `asset("storage/directory_name/filename")` to return the URL like you would for your CSS or whatever.